# How to do case insensitive search using QueryBuilder in CQ?

Tags: aem, query-builder

I am doing CQ search using Querybuilder on a set of 8 properties. One of them is a text box. So case insensitive search needs to be done on it. All others are drop downs.

Issue: Case sensitive search is happening on the text box.
Below mentioned in piece of code. When I include case insensitive code, the search is not happening properly.
Any pointers on this will be really helpful.

```
map.put("1_customcase.property", searchkey);
map.put("1_customcase.property.value", searchkey);
map.put("1_customcase.case", "no_case");
map.put("orderby", "customcase");**

map.put("2_property", propertyname);
map.put("2_property.value", value);
map.put("3_property", propertyname);
map.put("3_property.value", value);
...
...
...

Query query = builder.createQuery(PredicateGroup.create(map), session);
```

Comment: customcase predicate is not avaialable by default. Did you create one for that?

Comment: Didnt create on my own. Saw a blog related to this and tried the same. Am definitely missing something / doing something wrong here. Please help!  http://www.wemblog.com/2013/04/how-to-create-custom-query-predicate-in.html

Comment: I did try the same thing and it works. From your query i find that the propertyname and the propertyvalue are the same i.e., `searchkey`. Check if that is causing the issue.